# Can early exposure to stimulates, like ritalin, result in higher tolerance to them?

Tags: medications, insomnia, stimulants, add-adhd, drug-tolerance

As a child I was diagnosed with ADD and put on Ritalin from a young age.  As a child I use to have significant insomnia, but did not realize it was due to Ritalin until I finally stopped taking it much later, as I didn't realize my difficulty with sleeping was unusual or qualified as insomnia.

As an adult it seems as if I have an above-average tolerance to stimulants, especially considering I'm slim (if not short) and thus likely in in the lower 50th percentile for mass for males.

In particular I can drink a soda, or coffee, without any difficulty falling asleep or help 'waking up' when tired.  I also find that no AD/HD medication appears to have a significant affect on me.

I'm wondering if early exposure to stimulant like Ritalin could have resulted in a higher tolerance to stimulants in general, or if I'm just crazy :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, unfortunately, Ritalin produces a tolerance in individuals who take it.**

In the conclusion of this double blind trial, the author notes,

> **Acute tolerance to methylphenidate appears to exist.** This should be
>   considered in the design of an optimal dosing regimen for the
>   treatment of children with attention deficit hyperactivity disorder.

[Acute tolerance to methylphenidate in the treatment of attention deficit hyperactivity disorder in children.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10511066)

**Addendum:**

This might be a useful reference for ADHD in general:
[Attention Deficit Hyperactivity Disorder: Diagnosis and Management of ADHD in Children, Young People and Adults.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22420012)